# CSS: Romper una palabra sin espacios en una tabla

Tags: css

Tengo una palabra que no contiene espacios en blanco y quiero romperla cuando alcance la anchura que tiene su `<th>`, he ido probando con diferentes respuestas que he encontrado en stack pero no lo he conseguido.

```css
.romperpalabra{
display:inline-block;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="column1">COLUMN1</th>
  <th class="column2">COLUMN2</th>
  <th class="column3">COLUMN3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>hola1</td>
  <td class="romperpalabra">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2</td>
  <td>hola3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ibas bien, pero recuerda ponerle tamaños a los contenedores. Le estas diciendo que si, que parta, ¿pero donde?

```css
.romperpalabra{
  word-wrap: break-word
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
table{
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="column1">COLUMN1</th>
  <th class="column2">COLUMN2</th>
  <th class="column3">COLUMN3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>hola1</td>
  <td class="romperpalabra">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2</td>
  <td>hola3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar `overflow` para esconder el texto restante, pero vas a tener que añadirle un `width` al contenedor.

```css
.romperpalabra{
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="column1">COLUMN1</th>
  <th class="column2">COLUMN2</th>
  <th class="column3">COLUMN3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>hola1</td>
  <td class="romperpalabra">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2</td>
  <td>hola3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```